# Send email using smtp and Outlook.Office365.com

Tags: asp.net, email, office365

I am getting hung up on sending emails using outlook.office365.com and ASP.NET.

I am passing in the email address from my contact form as the "FROM" email.  If I change the "FROM" address from the contact form input to just "no-reply@mydomain.com" it works.  Apparently there is a missing step if you are sending emails from a different domain that what the mail server is on.

Here is my error: "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender".   I looked this up and the results were pretty much telling me to set permissions in my Outlook client, which I am not using.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.  Thanks

I am using the following authentication to send my emails:

```
//msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@plassonusa.com", "What's Up");
//This is the From I want to use.  The 1st one is the only one that works
msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text, "What's Up");
msg.To.Add(emailTo);
msg.Subject = "my subject";

msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = "foo";

msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("outlook.office365.com", 587)
{
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,                              
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("no-reply@domain.com", "mypassword"),
    EnableSsl = true
};

if (msg.To.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        smtpClient.Send(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var error = ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with all aspects of SMTP - but don't you think it'd be a big security flaw if you could just impersonate anyone's email address by setting the "from" address to whatever you want? Seems like MS disabled that, and for good reason.

Comment: This got me thinking.  I set up a reply to with the from email passed in and it  worked.  The only issue is that it says the email came from my no-reply@domain.com email instead of the actual form sender (the website visitor).

Comment: Instead of trying to use the user's email address as the "From", why don't you create a proxy account on your domain for them? For example, I use an online dating site. When I message another user through the site, they get an email from "mason@users.thedatingsite.com" that they can reply to. If they reply, then I'll get an email notification to my actual email address. And that notification email will appear to come from "stacy@users.thedatingsite.com" instead of her real address.

Comment: It is easier if you use port = 25.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by using the same email id for "From" which email id is used as SMTP user.

Comment: Good catch, this was my issue.

Comment: Glad to see it helped you.

Answer (score 6):

One thing that I see missing from your code that I have in mine is the following for the SmtpClient configuration:

```
client.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";
```

Also, my host value for sending is "smtp.office365.com" instead of "outlook.office365.com".

EDIT:

I just built this test case from my working code. This will send an email assuming that you have a valid email and password for the account you are sending from.

```
string sendFromEmail = "sendfrom@email.com";
string sendFromPassword = "TBD";

using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587))
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sendFromEmail, sendFromPassword);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(sendFromEmail);
    mail.To.Add("destination@email.com");

    mail.Subject = "Subject";
    mail.Body = "Test Email";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

    client.Send(mail);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll extract my entire code that I use for Office 365 and post it for you. Give me a few minutes to get it straightened out (environment vs. strings). :)

Answer (score 1):

In the below line

```
Credentials = new NetworkCredential("no-reply@domain.com", "mypassword"),
```

Remove "no-reply@domain.com" and use the actual From email address.

Answer (score -8):

To solve my issue, I simply change my smtpClient code to the following:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = "127.0.0.1"
        };
```

We have IIS6 set up on the server the site is hosted with.  We run the site through IIS7 but we run the mail server through IIS6.  No usernames, no passwords.  That's it.

Comment: This is not a solution for sending via Office 365 as you are using a local SMTP gateway that ignores any authentication of the sender. This is a spammers paradise as they can just mail away.